# iPhone external video playback from an app

Tags: iphone, video

I know the iPhone can play video on an external screen if you have the Apple component output cable.  I also know you can write an app that plays video.  Is there a way to put those two things together and write an app that will play video specifically on an external screen?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this to work? Apple unapproved methods are fine; it's just for a product launch so will never see the app store :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible with the iPhone API.  I have heard of apps that have done it on jail-broken phones, but there is not Apple-approved way of doing it at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using private private APIs, but it won't get in the store. This guy wrote a class to do it here: http://dragonforged.com/DFVideoOut.shtml  Haven't used it myself, but it looks very simple.